# How can I restore a MySQL Docker container that has crashed

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

After updating, my WordPress stopped connecting to the MySQL DB on docker.

So as of now, I start Docker, see the following logs:

```
2022-02-14 02:28:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.

2022-02-14 02:28:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2022-02-14 02:28:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.

2022-02-14T02:28:08.102455Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.

2022-02-14T02:28:08.102491Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) starting as process 1

2022-02-14T02:28:08.144825Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.

2022-02-14T02:28:08.625666Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.

2022-02-14T02:28:58.896407Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS dd_upgrade_garbage_80028' failed with error code = 3664, error message = 'Failed to delete SDI 'dd_upgrade_garbage_80028.columns' in tablespace 'mysql'.'.

2022-02-14T02:28:58.905477Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.

2022-02-14T02:28:58.905864Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

2022-02-14T02:28:59.332262Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Now as its a docker with a volume attached to /var/lib/mysql

I have all the data files, but as the server keeps on restarting, I have a very small window to run any commands on docker.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur if the MySQL container stops abnormally

First, make a backup of the data directory of MySQL container

You can try to upgrade the MySQL container version. Can you fix this problem

Comment: MySQL container is already on the latest version 8.0.28